# Azure Function App Blob Triggers using identity-based authentication returns a powershell error

Tags: python, azure, powershell

we have a function app with a blob trigger. Recently, I've migrated the trigger to an identity-based authentication according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python). It works well locally on my machine and on the function app. Note that the app is written in Python. Although, the error happens before the app is called so I doubt that language is a factor here.

My colleague recently started to collaborate on the function. When he tried to debug locally, he had this error as soon as he tried to launch the function (when the function would connect to the queue service for the triggers)

> An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down. Azure.Identity: Azure PowerShell authentication failed due to an unknown error. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I told him to install the Azure CLI and the error switched to:

> An unhandled exception has occurred. Host is shutting down. Azure.Identity: Azure PowerShell authentication failed due to an unknown error. 'pwsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The error clearly seems to be a missing powershell core CLI. What bugs me is that, apart from the windows-bundled powershell, pwsh is not a recognized command on my machine also. Therefore, I should be getting this error but I'm not while my colleague is.

Here's what we tried:

- We tried using a different storage account (same problem)
- Compared access level to both storage accounts (no differences)
- We tried authenticating with a key (It works)
- We haven't tried installing Powershell Core for the reason mentionned previously

We work on Windows 10 19044

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:55:00",
  "extensions": {
    "blobs": {
      "maxDegreeOfParallelism": 1
    },
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "PROJECT/documents/{name}",
      "connection": "PROJECT"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#local-development-with-identity-based-connections).

The authentification goes through the Azure CLI when it fails to get user context from VSC. So, this explains why my colleague and I had different results. For me, the program would authenticate using my VSC credentials while it didn't work for my colleague.

To solve this, we:

- Signed out of VSC and logged by in
- used `az login` to make sure it was working properly

Can't say for sure that it's the first step that solved it but it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons for this error the user (or system) PATH environment variable not containing the directory where the PowerShell executable located. It's usually located at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, and although the PATH variable contains the `C:\Windows\System32` directory, Windows may have problems finding the executable within its subfolders.

The solution entails setting the **PATH** environment variable to the directory where the PowerShell executable is located.

1. In the Windows search bar, type "**environment variables**" and select the appropriate Control Panel item.
2. A window called System Properties will open. At the bottom,  click "**Environmental Variables**."
3. Modify the **PATH** environment variable to include the path of the PowerShell folder.
4. The agent must be restarted in order for the changes to take effect. It's possible that you'll need to restart the computer to ensure that the new variable is picked up by all other Windows portions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.

Take note that the command "powershell" does work for the both of us.
It's the command "pwsh" that doesn't work for any of us.


Strangely enough, when I run the Azure Function locally, it probably doesn't use powershell core to authenticate with the blob storage.